Interpreting Mediation Model Result
I am testing a mediation model using SEM via Lavaan package in R and found that there is significant relationship between mediator variable and dependent variable. For example:
model1 <- '
  med ~ ind
  dep ~ med
'


However, if I include direct relationship in the model, the relationship between mediator variable and dependent variable becomes insignificant. For example:
model1 <- '
  #direct relationship
  dep ~ ind

  #mediation relationship
  med ~ ind
  dep ~ med
'

How do I interpret this result? Also, should I be using just mediation relationship in the model or also must include the direct relationship between dependent and independent variables?

[If you format your code, it's much easier to read. I've tried to do this but make sure it makes sense. Also, copy and paste your code from R, don't retype it. Your code had errors that meant it wouldn't have run. Again, I've tried to fix.]
This isn't about SEM, this is about mediation. You don't need to use SEM to test these models (but there is no harm in so doing).
Yes, generally you include the direct relationship, unless you have a good reason not to (your model chi-square should also guide you here). You should also use something like bootstrapping to get standard errors when doing mediation.
